# MVC4 areas problems(is already in the route collection)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

A route named 'Home_default2' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.

```
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "area/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {area="Home_Default", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }


        public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Home";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Home_default2",
            "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The auto generated code is bugging, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve this problem, just delete all the `.dll files` in your bin folder and then build the solution again. This should solve the problem for you.

Comment: Namespace change gave me this error, clearing out bin folders solved issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a duplicate `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); on route and on global.asax

so need only this:

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Changing Home_Default to Home.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had created an area & I had added this line in Route.config.

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

But this statement was already present in Application_start of global.asax. hence got the error.

So removed it from route.config. 
I did not change any route name for it. one route name was default (in RouteConfig file) & other was areaname_default (in AreaRegistration.cs file).